# How to find the directory structure and the file names under a php website?

Tags: php, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, httrack

How do i get the directory structure and filenames under a PHP website I do not own?. Not the code, just the structure and the filenames.?
I tried httrack, but since it's a PHP website, it doesn't work.

Comment: If you stop and think about this for a few seconds you will understand why you can't do this

Comment: What makes you think you SHOULD be able to do this.

Comment: I don't even need to find the filenames, just the directory structure. I purchased an app from codecanyon, the guy who sold me, or anyone for that matter, doesn't tell how to organize the backend and its structure. We are just fed up of it. So I thought if I could find the directory structure, i could help the others.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to extract the complete structure of a PHP website without having access to the server. You can maybe find out from where it pulls images and scripts by looking at `src` attributes of `script` and `img` tags as well as analysing the `href` attribute of `a` tags.
If you do find links containing strings like wp-includes or wp-content you can guess that it is a WordPress site for example which pretty much has a fixed structure.